# Arrow function in object definition

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, object-literal

In Javascript Harmony, we can for example do the following:

```
var maths = {
   sum (...args) {
      let r = 0;
      for (let num of args) {
         r += num;
      }
      return r;
   }
};
maths.sqr = n => n * n;
```

I just wondered if there is any way to use an arrow function, like `sqr` **within** the object definition, just like `sum`.

Comment: Yes you can do, But the this value will differ, It will not point to the maths object.

Comment: Can you provide syntax for this, please?

Comment: `var maths = { sqr : n => n * n; };` Here you go.

Comment: Nice, thanks. That would be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just write it as literal.

```js
var maths = {
        sqr: n => n * n,
        sum (...args) {
            let r = 0;
            for (let num of args) {
                r += num;
            }
            return r;
        }
    };

console.log(maths.sqr(5));
console.log(maths.sum(2, 4, 5));
```

Comment: My `sum` is not wrong, it just uses another syntax. I wondered if we can use the same syntax without `:`, but apparently not, as your example shows.

Comment: i have never seen this.